# Right way to consume a Web Service in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a Web Service like ServiceA.asmx. What is the right way to consume it?

I have two ways to consume a service:

**1)adding Service Refernce:**
 I have added Service Refernce of ServiceA.asmx ( Like in http://microsoftfeed.com/2011/part-14-how-to-consume-a-web-service-in-windows-phone-7) and i am able to call the Functions in Service like in the link i have given. If we use this way there is no need to parse the Result, Result returned in Objects(easy to use).

**2)Hitting the URL and Calling asynchronously:**
Here we can hit the URL, that function will call the asynchronous function that asynchronous function will return the response. But here response will be in XML here we have to parse that XML in to an Object.(not easy if any Big XML is there)

Please Guide me on this

Comment: I don't understand. You listed only advantages for the first solution, and only drawbacks for the second solution. Is there any reason you're considering the second one at all? As long as the first one does what you want, stick with it.

Comment: Here i want use the MVVM architecture, IF i use the First Solution what will be the Model  class in the sense what will be there in Model Layer?.

Comment: Your wrapper around the service code generated by VS is in your MVVM service layer. The model is whatever object returned by the service (or a custom wrapper around that object).

Comment: Thanks alot for your comments. But I am still unable to use 'INotifyPropertyChanged' interface because I am hitting the service from ViewModel and getting the response object though Async call, then I am firing the event to notify to the View. SO I think this is wrong because not using the INotifyPropertyChanged that has been suggested in MVVM. I think We have to use the 'INotifyPropertyChanged' interface to update the View, please correct me if anything wrongly understood.

Comment: You should call NotifyPropertyChanged when the Async webservice call returns. That will force the binding to update.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use the 'Add service reference' option. It's easy to use, and this option is added to Visual Studio especially for consuming web services. You can still use MVVM to build up your models/viewmodels.

I don't have the option to check it right now, but from my head the classes generated when adding the service reference also implement INotifyPropertyChanged. So you could probably use the object directly (if they are in the structure as you want to use it.) as your Model. Based on that model you can create your own ViewModel which you can bind to the UI.

To see how this works have a look at the code samples on MSDN:

[Implementing the Model-View-ViewModel Pattern in a Windows Phone Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521153%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

[Weather Forecast Sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229118)